# raect-admin image from canvas in simpleform

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-admin

I have canvas editor component that provide me base64 image data in SimpleForm of react-admin
How can i upload the image file to server ?
i am using data provider : https://github.com/benwinding/react-admin-firebase

```
 <Create {...props}>
        <SimpleForm>
            <TextInput source='location_name'/>
            <EditorComponent  />
        </SimpleForm>
    </Create>
```

I am new react and react-admin

Answer (score 0):

You can turn your component in the Input using the `<Field>` component or HOC `addField()` and save the image in base64 as part of the form:

https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Inputs.html#writing-your-own-input-component

https://redux-form.com/6.5.0/docs/api/field.md/